SwiftUI: How to animate changes within a ViewThatFits()
I am wondering if there is any way to animate the changes that happen inside a view that fits.
Below, I created a very rudimentary example to showcase what I mean. (I know I could bind the height of the rectangle directly to the state variable - this is just for the sake of the example.) Anyways, if the frame of the ViewThatFits is reduced, using the slider, at some point a switch to the fitting view occurs without any animation. This is what I would like to somehow animate (like with transitions, or a matched geometry effect, or the likes).
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 100.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Slider(value: $height, in: 10.0...100.0, step: 1.0)
            Spacer()
            ViewThatFits {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(height: 70.0)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(height: 30.0)
            }
            .frame(height: height)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Any ideas what I could try?

It is certainly not easy to animate the switch of views:

it seems .transition modifiers are ignored
trying to use .matchedGeometryEffect doesn't work either.

However, it seems that .onAppear and .onDisappear are called on the sub-views, at least. So you can use these to trigger transition-style animations when the views appear. The views still disappear without any animation though.
Boolean flags can be used to track the visibility of the views:
@State private var isRedShowing = false
@State private var isBlueShowing = false

If you only want to animate a change of view, but there should be no animation on initial show, then both flags should start off set to true.
Then, update the flags in .onAppear:
ViewThatFits {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.red)
        .frame(height: 70.0)
        .opacity(isRedShowing ? 1 : 0)
        .onAppear {
            isRedShowing = true
            isBlueShowing = false
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: isRedShowing)
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.blue)
        .frame(height: 30.0)
        .scaleEffect(isBlueShowing ? 1 : 0)
        .onAppear {
            isBlueShowing = true
            isRedShowing = false
        }
        .animation(.spring, value: isBlueShowing)
}

